# PMF with unknown n?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

During an experiment trial of $n$ tossed coins I have $X_1 ∼ B(n, 0.5)$.
It means I have a binomial r.v. that expresses the chances of success - landing heads $(x = 1)$ as $0.5$.

When tossing again the remaining coins $R_1 = n - X_1$ we can derive $X_2$.

My question are

1. Does this mean that on the second trial r.v. becomes $X_2 ∼ B(n - X_1, 0.5)$
2. Also I know that capital letters represent a variable. In this case should $R_1$ be considered one? How can I find the pmf of $X_2$ while $n$ **is unknown**?

I'm trying to wrap my head on these concepts. Kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: $\text{Bin}(n-X_1,0.5)$ cannot be recognized as a distribution since the parameter $n-X_1$ is a random variable. Actually it is bunch of distributions: one for every $\omega$ "...while $n$ is unknown…" Do you want to find the PMF of $X_2$ expressed in $n$?

Comment: So, $R_1$ corresponds to another random variable correct?
Yes my question is if it is possible to find the pmf expressed as n (in a generalized form).

Comment: I suspect that in a first round $n$ coins are tossed, and after that in a second round $R_1=n-X_1$ coins are tossed where $X_1$ has appeared to be the number of heads achieved in the first round. Then $X_2$ denotes the number of heads in the second round. If my interpretation is okay then indeed $R_1$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$P(X_2=k)=\sum_{i=0}^nP(X_2=k\mid X_1=i)P(X_1=i)$$

Here $P(X_2=k\mid X_1=i)=P(Y_i=k)$ where $Y_i\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n-i,0.5)$

Note that $P(X_2=k\mid X_1=i)=0$ if $k+i>n$, so actually you only have summate for $i\leq n-k$ .

Can you work this out yourself?

---

edit:

$\begin{aligned}P(X_{2}=k) & =\sum_{i=0}^{n}P(X_{2}=k\mid X_{1}=i)P(X_{1}=i)\\
 & =\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}P(X_{2}=k\mid X_{1}=i)P(X_{1}=i)\\
 & =\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-i}{k}0.5^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}0.5^{n}\\
 & =\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-i}{k}\binom{n}{i}0.5^{2n-i}\\
 & =\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{i}0.5^{2n-i}\\
 & =\binom{n}{k}0.5^{n+k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}0.5^{n-k-i}\\
 & =\binom{n}{k}0.5^{n+k}\left(1+0.5\right)^{n-k}\\
 & =\binom{n}{k}0.5^{n+k}1.5^{n-k}
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: Been doing some reading and still can't seem to work this out. You are attempting to get the conditional probability based on previous X1 r.v correct? Why are you multiplying by $P(X_1 = i)?$

Comment: $\{X_2=k\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^n\{X_2=k\cap X_1=i\}$ so that $P(X_2=k)=\sum_{i=0}^nP(X_2=k\cap X_1=i)$. Further $P(X_2=k\cap X_1=i)=P(X_2=k\mid X_1=i)P(X_1=i)$ by definition.

Comment: Check my edit on mistakes, please.